# Write operation is happening from 1 Gigabit port instead of 10 Gigabit port in NetGear switch and its random

Tags: switch, bonding, netgear

We have a Synology system which is connected with NetGear switch. We passed 2, 10 gigabit cables from synology to switch. We connected HP server with switch with 2, 10 gigabit port. We connected one more network on 1 gigabit port to a switch. We installed VMWare on the server and testing write test on Synology system. While testing, some time write operation is going through 1 gigabit port. The NetGear switch is smart enough to route the traffic to the fastest connection (i.e. from 10 gigabit port). This thing is happening on random. Sometimes write operation is going through 1 gigabit port and sometime its going through 10 gigabit port. We are performing write test from the server which is connected with two 10 gigabit port.

Comment: Not enough info and explanation of how you've connected the 1Gbit ports isn't clear at all.

Comment: Switches do not route.

Answer (score 5):

Configure your ESXi hosts so that storage traffic cannot traverse the 1Gb NIC. It's as simple as that.

Comment: We disabled the 1 Gig nic on the server and only 10 Gig nic is enabled, then also traffic is goin through 1 gig port into the synology. Synology has two 10 gig ports and four 1 gig port, we want to make use of four 1 gig ports too, thats why we connected 1 gig ports of synology into the switch. When we are writing from server, data is travelling viz 1 gig port to the synology instead of 10 gig port, if we restart the server (which hosts VM) then it transfers from 10 gig port. It is random.